# Shuffle array after 3rd element in foreach ? PHP

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

I need shuffle $items after 3rd element.

Result should be :
1 2 3 6 7 9 8 5 4

My is Code:

```
<?php
    $items= range(1, 10); shuffle($items); foreach($items as $v): 
?>
   ...
<?php 
  endforeach; 
?>
```

Cant find any solution in stackoverflow or google.
How can I do this ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the array in two parts and merge them after the suffle.

Edit; I now use array_splice to split the array at 3 and shuffle the remaining then merge them.

```
$items = range(1,10);
$items1= array_splice($items, 0,3);
shuffle($items);

$result = array_merge($items1, $items);
Var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/iUQ1m

Comment: Its simple and beautiful , but  how can i do that if i dont use range for my items ?

Comment: @ArikDonowan Then you can use [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get $item1 and $item2 from the original.

Comment: As Magnus says, array slice. Updated answer or splice as i used in answer.

Comment: @ArikDonowan is this OK?

Answer (score 2):

We can get first 3 elements and then shuffle others.

```
$items = range(1, 10);
for (var $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
   $aRes[] = array_shift($items); 
}
shuffle($items);
foreach($items as $v) {
   $aRes[] = $v;
}
```